# How long should I wait for plaster to dry/cure between coats?

Tags: plaster, masonry

Even though I am in the U.S., my city row house is old and the brick walls attaching to neighbors on each side have an inch thick plaster.  During the recent demolition/renovation, I had to tear some of it off and now I have a few strips to refill.

I have already done this job and am well familiar with the procedure, I even mix my own special mix from ingredients each of which comes from a different store (one of them being hydraulic lime as opposed to cement).  I do two coats of coarse plaster (2.5x masonry sand, 1x lime) and then one final coat of fine plaster (1.5x super fine silica white sand, 1x lime).  However, every time I waited two days before coats so that the previous coat is solid dry and adhered to the wall so that the new coat doesn't weigh the whole application off.  I am questioning my time period as too long.

Is it possible that a coat is ready to be reapplied sooner than that and how long?

Comment: This [DIY Article](http://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/three_coat_plaster.html) seems to recommend that the first coat be allowed to harden before the second coat is applied, but nothing is mentioned about waiting "too long".